# Fetch the row which has the Min values for multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get ID, min(YEAR_A), min(QUARTER_A), min(YEAR_B), min(QUARTER_B) for each ID:

```
ID   TOTAL_A   TOTAL_B   YEAR_A   QUARTER_A   YEAR_B   QUARTER_B    
----------------------------------------------------------------
10      100      200      2005       1         2016       4  
10      100      200      2005       2         2016       3    
10      100      200      2005       3         2016       2    
10      100      200      2005       4         2016       1    
11      200      300      2011       1         2018       4    
11      200      300      2011       2         2018       3    
11      200      300      2011       3         2018       2    
11      200      300      2011       4         2018       1
```

The result should be:

```
ID   TOTAL_A   TOTAL_B   YEAR_A   QUARTER_A   YEAR_B   QUARTER_B    
----------------------------------------------------------------
10     100       200     2005         1       2016         1  
11     200       300     2011         1       2018         1
```

The following query do the job but it is not efficient

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ID,
    TOTAL_A, YEAR_A, QUARTER_A,
    TOTAL_B, YEAR_B, QUARTER_B
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ID,
         TOTAL_A, YEAR_A, QUARTER_A,
         TOTAL_B, YEAR_B, QUARTER_B
         MIN(YEAR_A) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) MIN_YEAR_A,
         MIN(QUARTER_A) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) MIN_QUARTER_A,
         MIN(YEAR_B) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) MIN_YEAR_B,
         MIN(QUARTER_B) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) MIN_QUARTER_B
     FROM 
         TABLE)
WHERE
    YEAR_A =  MIN_YEAR_A
    AND QUARTER_A = MIN_QUARTER_A
    AND YEAR_B = MIN_YEAR_B
    AND QUARTER_B = MIN_QUARTER_B
ORDER BY
    ID;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please format your data so that it is readable.

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, ***PLEASE*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! (don't mess around with all those HTML tags - this is **NOT** a HTML based site - it uses **Markdown** instead)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select ID, min(YEAR_A), min(QUARTER_A), min(YEAR_B), min(QUARTER_B)
from table
group by ID;
```